# Long haul truck driver was not paid for his job

Tags: pennsylvania, salary, transportation

A friend of mine had been working for transportation company (contingently **company A**) as a long haul truck driver in PA state before leaving it for another one (due to the poor working conditions in **company A**). He was employed at **company A** for only 1 month, which comes up to 4 weeks, meaning 4 pay cycles.

However, while employed at **company A** and after leaving, he never received a single pay check from the company. Trying to connect with the company's audit department led to nothing, no one answers phone calls, no one responds to emails. Going directly to the lawyers for some $6K-7K doesn't sound reasonable. Is there may be some Labor Unions where the **company A** behavior can be reported?

My question is: what are the legal rights my friend can apply to the company in order to get at least his salary back?

Comment: Does he have a contract?

Comment: Even if they didn't provide that to him, I can legally request a copy correct?

Comment: Well, if they're going to break the law by not paying him, they may not be willing to provide a copy to prove it.

Comment: So what I'm thinking here is to find a statue in the PA "whatever" law, that specifically indicates the company should provide a copy of the contract by the legal request with handwritten signature of the employee

Answer (score 1):

It seems your friend can submit a [Wage Complaint form](http://www.dli.pa.gov/Individuals/Labor-Management-Relations/llc/Documents/llc-9.pdf) to the Bureau of Labor Law Compliance and have some recourse under section 9.1 of the Wage Payment and Collection Law. If your friend is in the right and the company doesn't follow through properly they could be liable for even more money than what they owe him, though there is also the possibility of a court case if the company decides to fight it.

I'd post a quote of the relevant section of law but the formatting of the online version of that wage law I found does not copy well: http://www.legis.state.pa.us/WU01/LI/LI/US/PDF/1961/0/0329..PDF

This may be a better link: http://www.legis.state.pa.us/cfdocs/legis/LI/uconsCheck.cfm?txtType=HTM&yr=1961&sessInd=0&smthLwInd=0&act=329&chpt=0&sctn=9&subsctn=1

A more readable summary can be found in http://www.dli.pa.gov/Individuals/Labor-Management-Relations/llc/Documents/llc-2.pdf under Collection of Unpaid Wages.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I will ask if he has a contract in hands and will carefully go over the payments section.